# What animal makes these sounds?

Tags: zoology

An animal near where I live in Austria is making these sounds. I'm thinking it is in distress, but I can't find it. Can anyone tell me what it is?

It goes quiet when you get close, but responds heavily to a cat meowing. The environment is a residential area with many rather large gardens. I haven't heard it make any noise after sundown, only throughout the day, morning til evening. There is a small stream nearby, but no larger bodies of water.

https://whyp.it/tracks/116934/unknown-animal?token=bqQEa

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Can you please edit your question with a couple of details: What sort of environment are you in (rural, urban, semi-rural)?, are there any bodies of water nearby - rivers, lakes, streams etc?, and what time of day does this happen?

Comment: @bob1 Thank you for the guidance, I have added more details.

Comment: Sounds like a kitten in distress to me. Maybe an abandoned one or if it's at particular times, maybe when it's mother leaves. I am not sure enough. Somebody please confirm.